# export temporary files to another folder in org to latex export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559753/emacs-org-mode-export-to-another-directory/47850858#47850858) you will find the following code. What I would like to change is that the pdf and html will not go to that folder. Place only service files such as tex files there.

```lisp
(defun org-export-output-file-name-modified (orig-fun extension &optional subtreep pub-dir)
  (unless pub-dir
    (setq pub-dir "exported-org-files")
    (unless (file-directory-p pub-dir)
      (make-directory pub-dir)))
  (apply orig-fun extension subtreep pub-dir nil))
(advice-add 'org-export-output-file-name :around #'org-export-output-file-name-modified)
```

Some idea?

Comment: Because of how `org-latex-export-to-pdf` has been implemented, which passes `#'org-latex-compile` as the POST-PROCESS argument in `org-export-to-file`, what you are asking is a little cumbersome to achieve. Maybe you could use `(setq org-latex-remove-logfiles t)`, to remove most 'service files'? Would that be sufficient?

Comment: It is an idea that I have been considering, but it is not ideal because sometimes you have to analyze the .tex files.
A colleague has made a code in Lisp so that once compiled it moves the files to a folder which I have hidden for greater cleanliness. It is not an ideal solution because it is not native but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This code works, but how i say no it's a native solution

```
(defun org-latex-move-exported-files (&optional arg)        
  "Mueve los archivos generados por latex a un directorio al final de la exportación." 
  (ignore arg)                                                                      
  (let ((latex-output-dir "./latex/")             
        (latex-files (directory-files "." nil "\\.lot\\|\\.lof\\|\\.tex\\|\\.log\\|\\.aux\\|\\.out\\|\\.toc"))) 
    (unless (file-exists-p "./.latex/")                         
      (mkdir ".latex" "."))
    (when latex-files                              
      (dolist (file latex-files)  
        (when (file-exists-p file)  
          (rename-file file (concat latex-output-dir (file-name-nondirectory file)) t)))  (message "Se movieron los archivos de LaTeX generados por Org al directorio ./latex/"))))
(advice-add 'org-export-dispatch :after 'org-latex-move-exported-files)
```